# getting a random input from a list that has been placed into a textbox with C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, random, sendkeys

Am trying to solve this issue I have for work I saw that selenium is quite useful and I wanted to save time and energy doing the same task everyday so I tried making a really basic way to solve the current issue I have with C# and Selenium I need to do the following.
I'm trying to figure out how I could connect a textbox (multiple text input) to then randomly pick one and send it to a webpage. This is my code so far:

```
namespace emails
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //textbox input
        string quest = question1.Text;

      
        var random = new Random();
        var names = new List<string> { question1.Text};
        int index = random.Next(names.Count);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\webdrivers");
        ChromeDriver drv; Thread th;
        string url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin";
         
        
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("whsOnd")).SendKeys(question1.Text); Thread.Sleep(2000);

        


    }
}
}
```

I tried this but as expected this would just send the whole textbox input.

Comment: What is `question1.Text` ?

Comment: its the textbox for the input

Answer (score 0):

Assumimg question1 contains several lines and you want to pick 1 line, ie question1 is:

```
SomeLineWhichIsaName
AnotherLineAnotherName
SomeMoreName
```

You want to split question1 on linebreaks, which gives you a list of lines (3 in this case, they seem to be names). Than your random function works.

```
var names = question1.Text.Split("\r\n");
int index = random.Next(names.Count);
string randomName = names[index]; 
 driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("whsOnd")).SendKeys(randomName)
```

\r\n or \r or \n => just figure out what works

Comment: the issue is when I try to connect the following code under a text box for example  if 
 I input the following names into the textbox : "alex","david","john" i would need to divide  those names so that when i click the button to start it would start the browser and send the first name and then the "david" in another text field and the same procedure for "john". The issue arises when i try to connect the textbox in such a way that it would work with a "START" button.

Comment: I do not entirely get what you want. Any of these? **1)** enter text 1, click start, enter text 2, start, enter text 3, start **2)** enter text 1, text 2, text 3, click start. Please edit the original question with a concrete example, so we can give a better answer